# PHP redirect subdomain to main domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, root, subdomain

I'm working on a multi-language page but have one problem with sub-domains.

I want to use the url `en.example.com` and I want read all from example.com/index.php (and set image , CSS- root as example.com) But in browser I want still URL `en.example.com` and all data are read from example.com and cannot set or change any relative path for images, includes , CSS...  Because now I have one url for more language (set in session and cookies) and this is not good solution for google. And I want change it with the smallest impact on code.

it is possible? for example htaccess or other way? thank you for answer.

Roman

add:

i try

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en.example.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.en.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

but this code change url address .

thank you for help

Comment: `htacees` if you mean `htaccess` then yes. htaccess can redirect whitout changing the URL in the browser.

Comment: Yes i mean htaccess (sorry for english) .

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to include the php file from the other virtualhost:

```php
<?php
require '../../example.com/public_html/index.php';
?>
```

This will allow what you want, but it's not always possible depending on your virtualhost configuration. This example should work if you're running all domains under the same DirectAdmin user.

Comment: i try it as first , but problem is in relative path of images and css files.

Comment: Use absolute paths for asset files, or use base href.

Comment: You could also symlink the asset directory. It's a little dirty but saves a lot of work changing paths and it prevents extra http requests caused by htaccess redirects.

Comment: thank you vinz, symlink is super sollution all work perfectly.thank you

Answer (score 0):

[mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) helps with two things, rewrite and redirect.

- It is called rewrite, when a request is changed internally, without the client noticing.
- It is called redirect, when a request is changed and the client notified, to fetch the resource from somewhere else.

A request is redirected in two cases

- a `RewriteRule` has appended a [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag, as in

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  ```
- or when a `RewriteRule`'s target URL is an absolute URL pointing to another host, e.g. when the request is for `en.example.com` and the target is

  ```
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L]
  ```

---

So, if you want to keep the requested URL unchanged in the browser, you must not use an `R` flag and you must not change the host part.

If you really need to map a remote server, you may try the [`P|proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) flag

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [P]
```

For this to work, the [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) module must be enabled.

Note also the performance warning

> **Performance warning**
>   Using this flag triggers the use of mod_proxy, without handling of persistent connections. This means the performance of your proxy will be better if you set it up with ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch

Comment: i try it but it is not work correctly. Url was always change to www.example.com